isPointInPath method does not recognize the correct pixels
I have an variable that stores path2D which is used to draw a polygon on the screen.
After drawing this polygon, I want to change its color and I need this to be done by iterating through the canvas pixels and changing it manually. The code works fine for most pixels, but some pixels are being mistakenly considered as part of the path (specifically 1 column 1 pixel further to the right and a row 1 pixel further down).


const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D();

let squareX = 0;
let squareY = 100;
let squareSize = 50;

path.lineTo(squareX, squareY);
path.lineTo(squareX + 60, squareY);
path.lineTo(squareX + 60, squareY - 60);
path.lineTo(squareX, squareY - 60);

context.fillStyle = "red";

context.fill(path);

setTimeout(() => {
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
  var data = imageData.data;
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var index = (y * width + x) * 4;
      if (context.isPointInPath(path, x, y)) {
        data[index] = 0;
        data[index + 1] = 255;
        data[index + 2] = 0;
        data[index + 3] = 255;
      }
    }
  }

  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}, 500);
<canvas width="350" height="350"></canvas>



I used setTimeout to make the difference more visible.
Why is this happening? How could I solve this problem?

OK, thanks. I added a canvas--please adjust if that's not actually part of your code, or the width/height aren't right. You might want to move the square up a bit so it shows up more cleanly in the snippet frame. Anyway, the code seems to work in the snippet, so you may be missing something important. The red square turns completely yellow for me on firefox after 500 ms.

Yes, it turns yellow, but its dimension increases by one pixel in width and height. If you zoom in you will notice.

To prove this, I ran a console.log and noticed that some white pixels were being considered as parts of the path

OK, thanks for clarifying. You may want to put that square on the corner of the canvas, with a border, so the edge is clearer. Yellow blends in with white so I'd use green or something that stands out better.

Only see green pixels on Latest Chrome (V124.0.6367.92 (64-bit)) current 64bit Win11 (V23H2 build 22631.3447). Please indicate browser and OS

Each pixel is like a 1×1 square, and you’re checking if the top-left corner of each pixel is in the path; apparently a point on the boundary is considered to be in the path. Easy enough to fix in a few ways for a square with integer dimensions, but for general paths, it’s not even the case that one pixel will represent solely either the inside or the outside (i.e. it’ll be a color between the background and the polygon). Why do you need this to be done by iterating through the pixels? And separately, can you draw it with isPointInPath to begin with to avoid any discrepancies?

@Ry- Yes, drawing it with isPointInPath at first solves my problem, but I'm still puzzled as to why this phenomenon occurs. isPointInPath inaccuracy or something?

I can expand on that in an answer, but can you explain why you need this to be done by iterating through the pixels? For most purposes it’d be pretty inefficient and inaccurate, so it has XY problem vibes.
